# Scheduling after clock_nanosleep on Linux. Improving wake up time

Tags: linux, scheduling, sleep

I have a requirement to maintain 10ms intervals as precisely as possible.

I use clock_nanosleep with absolute time waking up point (increased for 10ms after each wake up) and CLOCK_MONOTONIC obviously.

On my desktop Ubuntu 11.04 clock_gettime called after waking up shows that my program wakes up on average 1ms late.

Now playing with Linux scheduler modes:

- SCHED_IDLE, program wakes up 2ms late on average
- SCHED_RR, program wakes up 0.9 ms late on average...

Results are the same whether the system is idle or running a few copies of :
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null 
for an aritifical cpu load.

My scheduler params (sched min granularity, wake up granularity, sched latency) were decreased to be as little as allowed but it didn't make any difference.

I haven't tried on any other desktop, not sure if it's expected precision I could get with clock_nanosleep with stock Ubuntu and Intel core i5 or there is something wrong with my system.

PS. At the end of the day such clock_nanosleep behavior leads to increasing latency during audio playback (underruns) when NON-blocking calls are uesd to deliver data to an audio device, relaying on blocking calls solves the problem, like there are no scheduling issues when using and waking up after blocking calls.

Comment: I guess you can't really demand keeping precise sleep intervals from a  OS that's not realtime. I'm curious to see where this goes, though.

Comment: That's true about realtime, but Skype running on the same desktop, does a lot of clock_nalosleep calls per second according to "strace" during an audio call, and they don't seem to incur any latency from what I can hear.

Comment: The chrt command allows realtime scheduling of a process.  If you actually need precision timing try: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-real-time-scheduling-priority-process/   This has issues of its own, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks, I used chrt first during the tests, then switched to pthread_setschedparam. SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO decreased "oversleeping" only by 10%, probably because my system was almost idle anyway.